# How to set the error output stream for lua in c++

Tags: c++, lua

I've implemented lua in my c++ project but right now it writes all errors and syntax errors to the console. Is there way to set a custom function in c++ to receive the errors instead?

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/555524-lua-error-handling/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your Lua code using [lua_pcall](http://www.lua.org/work/doc/manual.html#lua_pcall) and retrieve your errors from the result.